# Hot to not rely on atomic creation of dependencies with GNU Make?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

In my build system, some header files are generated automatically. Their generation takes some time. The generator first creates an empty file in the filesystem, then writes the content - so there is a small time window during which the file exists and is empty.

This leads to parallel build errors: process A needs header `file.h` and launches its generation command. Process B needs the same file; if it appears to start the compilation during the mentioned time window, the compiler sees the dependency in place, gets the empty header and aborts on a compilation error.

**What is the correct way to fix such problem?** I'm looking for a solution for GNU Make, but general considerations are also highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you generate the file giving it another name and then rename when it is fully generated.

Comment: The tool is broken. It shouldn't do that. But parallel make shouldn't start a job that lists a prerequisite on a file until the rule that generates that file is completed. Do you have your rule and prerequisites set up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given *make* the full story.
Simply tell it what recipe makes the header file in question,
and your parallel builds with start working.

This can be a little tricky to get right if the same recipe builds several headers at once.
The only way of encoding this in *make* is with pure pattern rules,
and I am not a fan of those
(you want the pattern to match only your explicit list of headers, no more).
Inevitably though,
the headers don't end up with the same timestamp
(`ls -l -t --full-time`),
so you could pretend that they are made one after the other.

A sketch:

```
# Headers created by the recipe are h0.h h1.h h2.h

h0.h: h1.h
h1.h: h2.h
h2.h:
    recipe line 1
    recipe line 2
```

Now when *make* wants to compile `f.c` that includes `h1.h` (say),
it realises that it must wait for `h2.h` to be built by its recipe,
and only then start the compilation of `f.c`.